# How to check if volume population has finished

Tags: docker, volume, mount

Imagine the following scenario:

I have a Docker image with a lot of small files in some folder called `/app`. I do then add a bind mount to that folder on a slow, network file system (`/dfs/volumes`; in my case it's based on Ceph): `docker run -v /dfs/volumes/app:/app ...`, as soon as the container starts, docker starts populating the volume. On the host I can see how `/dfs/volumes/app` is filled up with files, the container is running at this point. So far so good.

However: since the container is already running and at some point my entry point `/app/executable` will be executed, this might result in a problem because I do not know if the volume is already fully populated.

Is there a way to delay the container startup until the volume is completly populated? Or can I somehow check if population is done from inside the container? I could probably manually prepare the volume before I start the container, but that kind of defeats the purpose of the automatic volume population...

Comment: as i understand docker container is just completed starting process when all volumes are mounted. In your case, the execute file is stored in volume right ?

Comment: With the construct you show, Docker itself won't copy any files, it has to be something in the container running a `cp` command or similar.  There's a confusing feature where Docker can copy content into empty named volumes, though I'd avoid it if possible.  In this case the container process won't execute until the volume is fully populated.  Do you have a specific example where you've observed things behaving differently?

Answer (score 0):

ok, found out whats happening, this was related to the setup being distributed:
the volume is shared between two containers on different hosts. as soon as the first container starts, it starts populating the volume, and the other container "sees" an existing volume with that already has some files in it, so it simply starts booting.
and then for the 2nd container, the files appear over time.
my bad.
anyway, i leave this here for reference, in case someone runs into similar problems.